# XCode - UIWebView Not Loading

Tags: xcode, uiwebview

I have two local .html files in the Resources folder.  I'm trying to load them the following way, but only the final page loads.  What am I doing wrong?

File = please_wait.html

This one does not work.

```
NSError *error;
NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"please_wait" ofType:@"html"];
NSString* htmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
[webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]];   

 //Big "do-while" loop here.  It works fine so I omitted it.
```

File = update_graph.html

This one does not work

```
 path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"update_graph" ofType:@"html"];
 htmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
 [webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]];

//Lots of code removed.  All works correctly and doesn't touch webview
```

This last one works perfectly.  Google displays.

```
string = @"http://google.com";  
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: string];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:requestObj];
```

Comment: Are you sure "please_wait.html" is in you project, or maybe a mis-spelling of some form!

Comment: Yes it is.  If I try to access either of the htmlString parts by them selves by commenting out other stuff they work, they just get skipped over when combined with other code.  (And its not just it goes so fast I don't notice.  I add breakpoints and they still dont show up unless they are the only code there)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears from your comment that your `UIWebView` loads just fine, but it does not get a chance to refresh itself on the screen until you exit your method. It is not enough to set a break point inside the method and wait for the view to load: you must exit the method before iOS realizes that it needs to call `UIWebView`'s `drawRect` method.

To fix this, split your method in three parts, `A` `B` and `C`, and set `UIWebView`'s delegate in `A` to invoke `B` on `webViewDidFinishLoad:`, and the delegate in `B` to call `C`.

Here is how to implement this: start with a delegate that can call a selector when the loading has completed:

```
@interface GoToNext : NSObject <UIWebViewDelegate> {
    id __weak target;
    SEL next;
}
-(id)initWithTarget:(id)target andNext:(SEL)next;
-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView;
@end

@implementation GoNext
-(id)initWithTarget:(id)_target andNext:(SEL)_next {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        target = _target;
        next = _next;
    }
    return self;
}
-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    #pragma clang diagnostic push
    #pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Warc-performSelector-leaks"
    [target performSelector:next];
    #pragma clang diagnostic pop
}
@end
```

Now split your method into three parts - loading the first page, loading the second page, and loading the third page:

```
-(void)loadPleaseWait {
    NSError *error;
    NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"please_wait" ofType:@"html"];
    NSString* htmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
    webView.delegate = [[GoToNext alloc] initWithTarget:self andNext:@selector(loadUpdateGraph)];
    [webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]];
    // big do-while loop
}

-(void)loadUpdateGraph {
    NSError *error;
    NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"update_graph" ofType:@"html"];
    NSString* htmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
    webView.delegate = [[GoToNext alloc] initWithTarget:self andNext:@selector(loadGoogle)];
    [webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]];
    // Lots of code removed
}

-(void)loadGoogle {
    string = @"http://google.com";  
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: string];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webView loadRequest:requestObj];
}
```

Comment: So is there a way to tell my code to "wait" until it refreshes the page then continue?

Comment: Yep. You need to implement `- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView` as part of the `UIWebViewDelegate` messages.

Edit: If your code that should be executed after loading needs context that is not stored in your class, I would use a block. E.g. put your exit-code inside a block, pass it to your webview-controller class, save it as one of its members and do `self.myExitCodeBlock()` inside `webViewDidFinishLoad`.

Comment: @MrHappyAsthma Your function needs to exit , and let the main loop "do its magic". But you can do it with delegates the way I described in the second part of the answer.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to show what you mean by passing the delegate between the 3 parts of the method?  Im pretty new to Cocoa Touch stuff and I have no idea how to go about that.